# Forward Laraver 4 api calls

Tags: api, laravel-4

I have to forward all incoming request from api v1 to api v2. After finished process on the api v1 forward the same request to the api v2 and also process it. 
I don't know what is the best way to do it. But, I'll try to do it through *BeforeMiddleware* or perhaps add some kind of *filters on route*.
What do you think about these approaches? If someone had a similar problem, I'll be thankful if you share your solution with me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For this, here you can find a solution:
http://fideloper.com/laravel-http-middleware